# Import FilterLeafReader pylucene 4.9

Tags: lucene, pylucene

I use PyLucene 4.9.0-0 for a school project and I need to use FilterLeafReader but I can't figure out how to import this class.

I tried `from org.apache.lucene.search import FilterLeafReader` but i receive an import error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FilterLeafReader` does not exist in Lucene 4.9, and so is not available in PyLucene 4.9.

`AtomicReader` classes were renamed `LeafReader` in 5.0, so you should be using [`FilterAtomicReader`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/FilterAtomicReader.html) instead.  Also, in either case, it's in `org.apache.lucene.index`, not `org.apache.lucene.search`